# In a redis server side evaluated lua script should keys be used instead of scan?

Tags: redis

Given that you need to traverse the keyspace and that the script is going to block until it has finished regardless of what it is doing - is it better to just use 'keys' and get this over with as quickly as possibly as opposed to multiple calls to 'scan'?

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to iterate the entire keyspace, as this is a slow operation. If you really must do that, and insist on using server-side Lua, you'd be better off with `SCAN`, as it will not consume as much memory as `KEYS` may consume (for the reply).

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't scan be slower though, leading to the server being blocked for longer. If true does the memory consideration trump this?

Comment: You can benchmark to compare the two approaches, but IMO they'll preform similarly with scan being safer due to memory constraints